# Is there any way to insert a unique_ptr into a map in C++0x/gcc 4.4.7)?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gcc4.4

I can't figure out how to do it; it's driving me nuts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<std::string>> map;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> bar(new std::string("bar"));
    map["foo"] = std::move(bar);

    std::cout << "foo: " << *(map["foo"]) << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles just fine on gcc v4.9.2:

`$ g++ -std=c++0x test.cc -o test`

Unfortunately, all I have available to me is gcc v4.4.7, which produces a hideous error message that I'll stick at the bottom.

I can `push_back` `unique_ptr`s into `vector`s just fine; I don't understand why there's an issue with `map`.

I've also tried using `insert`:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<std::string>> map;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> bar(new std::string("bar"));
    auto pair = std::make_pair("foo", std::move(bar));
    map.insert(std::move(pair));

    std::cout << "foo: " << *(map["foo"]) << std::endl;
}
```

I can make the `pair` just fine, but when I try to `move` it into `insert` I get the error.  It appears that it's trying to call the copy constructor for some reason, but I don't understand why, since I'm `move`ing it.

`emplace` has the same result:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<std::string>> map;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> bar(new std::string("bar"));
    auto pair = std::make_pair("foo", std::move(bar));
    map.emplace(std::move(pair));

    std::cout << "foo: " << *(map["foo"]) << std::endl;
}
```

Both of these compile fine in g++ v4.9.2, but not in v4.4.7.

Anyone have any ideas on an alternative way to do this (in v4.4.7)?

Full error message output (from the first example):

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/char_traits.h:41, 
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:41,                
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,            
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream:40,           
                 from test.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/unique_ptr.h: In copy constructor 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::pair(const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:68:   instantiated from 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>::_Rb_tree_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&, _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:111:   instantiated from 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&, _Tp = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:394:   instantiated from 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>* std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_create_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&, _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:881:   instantiated from 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_(const std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, const std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, const _Val&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:1215:   instantiated from 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Val> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique_(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Val>, const _Val&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_map.h:540:   instantiated from 'typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, const std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Tp = std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_map.h:450:   instantiated from '_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Tp = std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >]'
test.cc:9:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/unique_ptr.h:214: error: deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Tp_Deleter>&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Tp_Deleter = std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:68: error: used here
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/map:60,
                 from test.cc:3:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h: In constructor 'std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>::_Rb_tree_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&, _Val = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:136: note: synthesized method 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::pair(const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::default_delete<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)' first required here
```

Comment: Try boost. 4.4.7 is too old to support the standard.

Comment: @n.m.: Boost cannot solve this. Including/linking Boost cannot magically add move semantics to the language.

Comment: Actually, gcc 4.4.7 in c++0x mode **has** support for move sematics:
https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit boost::unique_ptr was invented way way before move semantics.

Comment: @n.m.: What? "A unique_ptr is not CopyConstructible, nor CopyAssignable, however it is MoveConstructible and Move-Assignable." How else do you expect it to work? Are you confusing it with `std::auto_ptr`, which it replaced?

Comment: @SergeyA: Not full support. Read the _whole_ page you linked to, not just the one line that supports your argument out of context.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No I'm not, but perhaps I confused it with boost::shared_ptr which definitely was there before c++0x.

Comment: Well, you're likely on a Red Hat or CentOS system, in which case you can install devtoolset-3 and benefit from a newer compiler (with no runtime requirments if you need to deploy on a system that does not have a newer compiler installed). Other than that, you need to rewrite your code to not use unique_ptr.

Comment: @n.m.: Yes indeed. It was the traditional "mid-way" replacement for `std::auto_ptr` before we had the C++11 facilities to make `{boost,std}::unique_ptr` work.

Comment: move member has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC 4.4.7 does not provide full support for C++ 11 features, so it is unrealistic to expect all C++ 11 features to work properly. In this particular case, the compiler is not generating move assignment and move copy methods for you. So, when `std::map` attempts assignment or copy, it uses the regular default ones, which are deleted for `unique_ptr`.

If you just need a smart pointer, you can use `shared_ptr` instead.

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<std::string>> map;
std::shared_ptr<std::string> bar = std::make_shared<std::string>("bar");
map["foo"] = bar;
```

Comment: Good luck. He doesn't like this answer.

Comment: Compiler does not need to generate them, they are included in stl_map implemenation for gcc 4.4

Comment: Alright, so it's sounding like the answer to my question is simply "no" -- and that's fine; I'll figure something else out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into the issue. STL implementation for map correctly has a move constructor defined in it:

```
#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
      template<typename... _Args>
        _Rb_tree_node(_Args&&... __args)
    : _Rb_tree_node_base(),
      _M_value_field(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...) { }
#endif
    };
```

Moreover, this is called, as stated in the error output. `std::pair` has move constructor defined as well, but this one is not called.

I believe, `std::forward` and deduced type of Args is at fault:

> usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:
>   In constructor ‘std::_Rb_tree_node<_Val>::_Rb_tree_node(_Args&& ...)
>   [with _Args = const std::pair<..., std::unique_ptr<...> >&,

As you see, type of _Args is a const reference, which is forwarded by forward, and regular pair constructor is called.

I assume, one might fiddle with stl_tree.h to fix it - for example, by removing std::forward and just casting the arg to rvalue reference. This would not be correct, of course, but might work for specific case.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Honestly this is over my head, and unfortunately I can't go fiddling about with the STL headers for the same reasons that I can't simply upgrade to a more recent version of GCC, but I really appreciate you digging around. I think I'll just have to accept that what I want to do isn't possible and move on.